# Python new style class can not use __dict__ to update property attribute

Tags: python

```
>>> class foo():
...     @property
...     def o(self):
...             return 'o'
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.o
'o'
>>> f.__dict__['o'] = 'f'
>>> f.o
'f'
>>> class foo(object):
...     @property
...     def o(self):
...             return 'o'
...
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.o
'o'
>>> f.__dict__['o'] = 'f'
>>> f.o
'o'
```

The `__dict__` set just does't appear. Any ideas why?

I think maybe Python treat property differently inside, but I am not sure about it, if you write one property class in your own, the set is gonna work, otherwise not.

Comment: You should take a look at the various way to alter the [attribute access](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) in python. In particular `@property` creates a descriptor (see the linked material to understand what it is and how it works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property
def o(self):
    return 'o'
```

This is a non-data descriptor, i.e a property with no setter defined. Hence an instance attribute can override this property.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol):

> If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a
>   non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence.

So, to update a property, define its setter method as well.

And don't use instance's `__dict__` to access the setter or getter, internally `f.o = 'f'` for a setter is actually converted to:

```
type(f).__dict__['o'].__set__(f, 'f')
```

**Demo:**

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._o = 'o'

    @property
    def o(self):
        return self._o

    @o.setter
    def o(self, val):
        self._o = val

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.o
'o'
>>> type(f).__dict__['o'].__set__(f, 'f')
>>> f.o
'f'
>>> f.o = 'zzzz'  #this is equivalent to the previous call.
>>> f.o
'zzzz'
>>> type(f).__dict__['o'].__set__(f, 'foo')
>>> f.o
'foo'
```

Comment: I understand there might be some educationary advantage in using ``__dict__`` here all over the place (although I fail to see it), but why not mention ``getattr``/``setattr``? Maybe I have not understood the context entirely though.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Of course `setattr` and `getattr` are better choice than  that huge `__dict__` call, but I think OP's question was about how to do that using `__dict__`.

Comment: @JonasWielicki You can have a look at the `cached_property` implementation of *Django*.